# Set every element of TextBlockResult to visible when the value is not null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

i would like to make each element of textblockresult visible only when the value is not null.

Intent, ROKEntity, ProcedureName etc are strings that are defined as empty and then receive their value from a json :

```
string intent = "";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(root.XPathSelectElement("//intent").Value))
                {
                    intent = root.XPathSelectElement("//intent").Value;
                }

 resultToDisplay =   "Action: " + intent
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Rok Entity: " + ROKEntity
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Rok Entity: " + ROKEntity2
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Rok Entity: " + ROKEntity3
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Procedure Name: " + ProcedureName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Folder Name: " + FolderName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Task Name: " + TaskName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Worker Name: " + WorkerName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Risk Name: " + RiskName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "File Name: " + FileName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Workflow Name: " + WorkflowName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Model Name: " + ModelName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Position Name: " + PositionName
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Created by: " + CreatedBy
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Modified by: " + ModifiedBy
                            + Environment.NewLine + "From: " + From
                            + Environment.NewLine + "To: " + To
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Display Mode: " + DisplayMode
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Data Tracking: " + DataTracking
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Details: " + Details
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Export Format: " + ExportFormat
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Ged Files: " + GedFiles
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Ged Folders: " + GedFolders
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Map: " + Map
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Kpi: " + Kpi
                            + Environment.NewLine + "Procedure Type: " + ProcedureType


            TextBlockResult.Text = resultToDisplay;
```

ie i want **"Action: " + intent** to be visible only when the value of intent is not null nor empty, the same for **"Rok Entity: " + ROKEntity** and so forth ..

For the moment, i have the following xaml that only allows me to set the visibility of the whole lot to collapsed or hidden or visible:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockResult" Visibility="Collapsed" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" Foreground="Black"><Run Text="Result"/><InlineUIContainer>
```

What are the different steps to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can just skip the elements with empty or null value. So have a method like

```
private void AddToDisplay(StringBuilder sb, string title, string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        sb.Append(title);
        sb.Append(value);
    }
}
```

then build your result like

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
AddToDisplay(sb, "Action: ", intent);
AddToDisplay(sb, "Rok Entity: ", ROKEntity);
.
.
resultToDisplay = sb.ToString();
```

that way your results show only non-null non-empty elements and optionally hide the entire TextBlock if resultToDisplay is empty after you are done building it